# How to choose the optimal number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have constructed a game in Java.

It is a ski competition, the user will input the number of skiers, and they will run at a random speed to the bottom of the screen,
I did this using **threads** and **thread-pool**.

Every time the user chooses the number of competitors, the thread-pool will have that exact number, this seems a bit silly to me.

Is there a way to **determine the number of threads** to be most efficient for whatever input the user gives (Using a **lower number** of threads)?

Comment: You could just use a pool that adds threads as needed and let it pick the size. I'm not entirely sure what's being asked here though beyond that.

Comment: maybe [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) ?

Comment: It mostly depends on the number of available processors and the number of threads you can run on each. You've got a range `[1, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * threadsPerCore]` and you normalize the user input to the range.

Comment: The question is how I determine the optimal number, and @AndrewTobilko availableProcessors work in every JVM?

Comment: @AlexK I guess so. It's a part of the standard JDK